# App crashed during unwind segue in swift

Tags: swift, copy-paste, unwind-segue

I have implemented the copy-paste feature into a text box using the following function:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
var result = true
let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

if textField == numberField {
  if count(string) > 0 {
  let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
  let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil

  let resultingStringLengthIsLegal = count(prospectiveText) <= 6

  let scanner = NSScanner(string: prospectiveText)
  let resultingTextIsNumeric = scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd

  result = replacementStringIsLegal &&
           resultingStringLengthIsLegal &&
           resultingTextIsNumeric
  }
}
return result
}
```

Which works properly. but when we paste something into the text box and click on the back button for unwind segue app goes crash and give the following error:

[image]

Code for unwind segue:

```
@IBAction func unwindfromO(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {


}
```

Comment: Which function does the unwind segue calls? can you add the code please.

Comment: I added the code for unwind segue calls

Comment: can you delete the unwind segue and try recreating it. How about calling dismissViewController instead of unwind segue?

Comment: I implemented dismissViewController but app went to some other screen.